# WPF Add custom class event handler to HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

Essentially the problem that I have is that when I am trying to add an attribute to the checkbox in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in order to handle the checkbox's click event, I can't figure out how to assign the custom ModeNode's class handler `onclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)`. I can assign/create event handlers located to the main Window class which would also work just fine, but I think it is not the correct way to do it.

My .xaml file looks like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsInitiallySelected, Mode=OneTime}" />
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ModelNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox
                    Focusable="False" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                />
                <ContentPresenter 
                    Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" 
                    Margin="2,0"
                />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>    

    <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeView x:Name="SceneTreeView"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneTime}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
```

This is the datatype class I use for the treeview

```
public class ModelNode
{
    public List<ModelNode> Children { get; set; }

    public string Name { set; get; } = "";

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public ModelNode(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        IsChecked = false;
        Children = new List<ModelNode>();
    }

    public void AddChild(ModelNode m)
    {
        Children.Add(m);
    }

    public static void onclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        //logic to handle the Click event
    }

}
```

I'm a newbie on WPF so I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ModelNode` should have an `ICommand` property but not an event handler. You could then bind the `Command` property of the `CheckBox` to your `ICommand` source property:

```
<CheckBox  Command="{Binding CommandProperty}"
           IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

But you might as well handle the "event" logic in the setter of the `IsChecked` property. This one gets set when you check or uncheck the `CheckBox`:

```
private bool _isChecked;
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        //logic to handle the Click event

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm yeah actually adding the logic on the set is indeed an alternative and I think it does but I wanted to do, but its probably not serving the goal, which was to check the children nodes and update their status on the window. For some reason they remain unchecked even if their property has been updated

Comment: NVM just solved it implementing a NotifyPropertyChanged method :D I'm accepting the answer. Cheers :)